# Convergence in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces, inner-products

Suppose we have a nx1 vector $v_n = [\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} ...... \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}]^T$ in R^n, does is converge or diverge?

I initially thought it would converge to $\vec0$ since each of its entry $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow 0$, but then $\Vert v_n - \vec0 \Vert = \sqrt{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^2 \cdot n} = 1$, which shows that v_n doesn't converge to 0.

So I'm a little confused now. Any hints?

Comment: The problem is the convergence is in "what" sense. You have checked **pointwise** convergence and **norm** convergence. cf. https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Signal_Processing_and_Modeling/Signals_and_Systems_(Baraniuk_et_al.)/16%3A_Appendix_C-_Analysis_Topics_Overview/16.03%3A_Convergence_of_Sequences_of_Vectors

Comment: This is a sequence of elements from different sets, so it doesn’t really mean anything to ask out convergence. $v_1\in\mathbb R^1,v_2\in\mathbb R^2,\dots.$ Unless you meant the two $n$s different, then rename one.

Comment: What space do the $v_n$'s belong to? If each $v_n$ is in $\mathbb{R}^n$ it doesn't make sense to say that they converge as they aren't even in the same space. One thing you could do is consider each $v_n$ as an element  of $\ell^2$, the space of square summable sequences,  via the map$$v_n \mapsto \left(v'_n\right)_{n\geq 1} := \left(\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, \dots, \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, 0, 0, 0, \dots \right)\right)_{n\geq 1}.$$ Then what you have found is that though $\left(v'_n\right)_{n\geq 1}$ converges to 0 weakly, "pointwise" in a sense, it doesn't converge to 0 strongly/in norm.

Comment: If you think of $v_n\in\mathbb R^\omega,$ then it does not converge to zero, under the standard Euclidean distance, since the distance from $0$ is always $1.$